# Hide the paramater values passed in angular $location

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to add Parameters using `$location.search()` method like:

`$location.path('/myURL/').search({param: 'value'});`

This will lead to

`/myURL/?param=value`

How can I hide the parameter value in URL ?

Answer (score 0):

This `$location.search` does add this parameters as GET.

You can't hide GET parameters, because this is what those meant to work like.

If you doesn't like to display this params in the url, check for other alternatives to pass parameters.

You could place those params in a cookie or in a service (since there is no page reload all services will have this params persisted even after route changes)